# Existing Employee no Added again problem using java mysql

Tags: java

i am creating a simple employee leave payroll system.i run into the problem with while add the leave details. leave details  was duplicated. i am entering the leave information for all employees who working in the company.when the new employee joined when i enter the leave information to them. existing employee  also added again. i show the screen shot image below.what happen

**leave table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpHBE.jpg)

**registation table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4xs.jpg)

when the new employee join only add the new employee only. existing employee should not add again. what i tried so far i attached below.

code which i tried i attached below.

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/spay","root","");           
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        stmt = con.createStatement();

       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select empno from registation");

        while (rs.next()) {
          String empvalue = rs.getString("empno");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into leaves(empno,casual,annual,medical,year)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,empvalue); // employee no how to give 
            pst.setString(2, cas);
            pst.setString(3, anu);
            pst.setString(4, med);
            pst.setString(5, year);         
            pst.executeUpdate();


        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Leave Insertedddddd");
```

Comment: A) please avoid screen shots. Rather try to say in nicely formatted text what you intend to express B) ... I have so no clue what you are asking for. What is it that you expect how the people here can help you?

Comment: You are getting back all row from `registation`. Your while loop will insert a new row to `leaves` for every row in `registation`. I think you have to add some condition for that query. Something like `select empno from registation where name like ?` and provide a name for the people you want to add leaves.

Comment: can you write it sir how to add the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this `select empno from registation`, it will select all empno from the registation table... The ResultSet will have all the users in it...

So when you do this,

```
while (rs.next()) { //rs now has all the employee
      String empvalue = rs.getString("empno");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into leaves(empno,casual,annual,medical,year)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,empvalue); // employee no how to give 
        pst.setString(2, cas);
        pst.setString(3, anu);
        pst.setString(4, med);
        pst.setString(5, year);         
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
```

It adds all the employee again...

What you can do is, to put a conditional statement at the `select empno from registation`...

Eg. to only select a single user with '001' empno:

```
SELECT empno FROM registation WHERE empno = '001';
```

To select multiple employees, you can use the do something similar as below...

```
SELECT empno FROM registation WHERE empno = '001' OR empno = '002' OR empno = '003';
```

For this you can append as many `OR empno = '00X'` at the back as you want

or

To select the last entry in the table:

```
SELECT empno FROM registation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sir i tried this code it is working but but if there is new 3 employee added it only add last insert rcord only thats is problem. show last SELECT empno FROM registation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;